# chrome-extension websocket keep alive

Tags: google-chrome-extension, websocket, webrtc

I'm trying to develop my first chrome extension, basically porting SIPML5 phone into an extension.

Currently I get the extension to connect and function, but after any page navigation reload etc, it reconnects with the websocket server.

I am trying to read through the google documentation.  I have found https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#connect which explains long lived connections, but from what I understand, this also will disconnect on any page changes?

Is it possible to keep the websocket alive throughout page changes / navigation, if so, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank You.

Comment: Yes on any navigation the port gets disconnected. You can catch tab url update event for the tab and try reconnecting (ignore if you are doing the same). Or create connection port in background html or js. Hope I understood wats ur actual problem is :)

Answer (score 4):

Your WebSocket should live in a [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html), which is not affected by navigation.